# Boolean code not letting me calculate variables (python) (beginner)

Tags: python

```
high1 = float
high2 = float
final = float
score1 = float(input("Enter first score: "))
score2 = float(input("Enter second score: "))
score3 = float(input("Enter third score: "))

if score1 > score2:
   high1 = score1
   if score2 > score1:
      high1 = score2
      if score3 > score1 or score2:
         high2 = score3
      else:
          if score1 > score2:
             high2 = score1
             if score2 > score1:
                high2 = score2
                

final = (high1 + high2)
print(final)
```

I receive the following when trying to add those variables together

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'type' and 'type'
```

Comment: Hi. You don't need `high1=float` in Python. No need to declare your variable types :)

Comment: @Riya Well depending on the input you would need to declare high1 and high2 with a default value, like 0.

Comment: @user56700 indeed.

Comment: You probably do not want to nest those `if` statements within each other. Note that if `score1 <= score2`, *none* of those statements will be reached at all.

Comment: Welcome! Adding types in Python is not needed, but a good idea!  Try "high1: float" rather.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably with your input, the conditions have not existed to run the code in your `if` statements. Thus `high1` and `high2` are still just the *type* `float`, which doesn't work with `+`.

You should perhaps give `high1` and `high2` initial default values like `0` or `1`.

Be aware that `elif` exists.

> ```
> if score1 > score2:
>   high1 = score1
>   if score2 > score1:
>      high1 = score2
>      if score3 > score1 or score2:
>         high2 = score3
>      else:
>          if score1 > score2:
>             high2 = score1
>             if score2 > score1:
>                high2 = score2
> ```

Can be:

```
if score1 > score2:
   high1 = score1
   if score2 > score1:
      high1 = score2
      if score3 > score1 or score2:
         high2 = score3
      elif score1 > score2:
         high2 = score1
         if score2 > score1:
            high2 = score2
```

But really this is all just another way of writing:

```
high1, high2, *_ = sorted([score1, score2, score3], reverse=True)
```

If you must use a conditional statement, we can use `and` and `or` to combine multiple comparisons. This avoids excessive nesting, which can be difficult to mentally keep track of.

```
if score1 > score2 and score1 > score3:
   high1 = score1
elif score2 > score1 and score2 > score3:
   high1 = score2
else:
   high1 = score3

if score1 < high1 and score1 > score3:
   high2 = score1
elif score2 < high1 and score2 > score3:
   high2 = score2
else:
   high2 = score3
```